# Unhandled exception at in ConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, visual-c++

I'm trying to make a basic calculator in Visual studio where the user enters an equation and the equation is solved by taking the equation as a string and then modifying the string to give the solved equation.But when I put the equation I get the error when debugging:

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FF9A1411F28 in ConsoleApplication1.exe:
>   Microsoft C++ exception: std::invalid_argument at memory location
>   0x000000195B4FF680.

Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void Calculation_div(string &str);

int main()
{
    string a;
    cin >> a;
    Calculation_div(a);
    cout << a;
}
void Calculation_div(string &str)
{
    std::size_t div_a;
    std::size_t div_r, div_l;
    while(str.find('/')) {
        div_a = str.find('/');
        if (str.find('/', div_a + 1)) {
        div_r = str.find('/', div_a + 1);
        }
        else {
            div_r = str.length();
        }
        if (str.rfind('/', div_a - 1) ) {
            div_l = str.rfind('/', div_a - 1) ;
        }
        else {
            div_l = 0;
        }
        string bi_l = str.substr(div_l, (div_a - div_l));
        string bi_r = str.substr(div_a+1, (div_r - div_a+1));
        int in_l = stoi(bi_l);
        int in_r = stoi(bi_r);
        int res_i = in_l + in_r;
        string res_s = std::to_string(res_i);
        str.replace(div_l, res_s.length(), res_s);
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed, walk up the callstack to the line of your code causing this bug.

Comment: *But when i put the equation i get the error when debugging* -- It would also help if you told us what the data is that duplicates the problem, instead of hiding the data behind `cin` calls.

Comment: can you give an example of what is the value of string `a` you have entered ? equation example where you get the problem ?

Comment: the value of string a im using is a=22/22
Though I did find that the problem stops when i just declare div_l=0
it just never stops executing being on an infinite loop

Comment: *I'm trying to make a basic calculator in Visual studio where the user enters an equation and the equation is solved by taking the equation as a string and then modifying the string to give the solved equation.* -- First and foremost, your solution to this issue is not the way to go about this.  You should write a recursive descent parser instead of this adhoc code you put together.  Having said that, the error occurs due to you checking for `/` a second time, and assuming there is a second `/`.  Note that there isn't a single test for `std::string::npos` in your entire program.

Comment: Also, please read the documentation for [std::string::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).  An `npos` is returned on failure to find a character, not `false` as your code is assuming it does.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, Rookie mistake. Turns out i just assumed string.find would return a false value instead of string::npos.I edited the code so that it runs perfectly without any errors this time around

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

void Calculation(string &str);

int main()
{
string a;
cin >> a;
Calculation(a);
cout << a<<"\n";
system("PAUSE");
}
void Calculation(string &str)
{
std::size_t div_a;
std::size_t div_r, div_l;
while(str.find('/') != string::npos) {
    div_a = str.find('/');
    if (str.find('/', div_a + 1) != string::npos) {
        div_r = str.find('/', div_a + 1);
    }
    else {
        div_r = str.length();
    }
    if (str.rfind('/', div_a - 1) != string::npos) {
        div_l = str.rfind('/', div_a - 1);
    }
    else {
        div_l = 0;
    }
    string bi_l = str.substr(div_l, (div_a - div_l));
    string bi_r = str.substr(div_a+1, (div_r - div_a+1));
    int in_l = stoi(bi_l);
    int in_r = stoi(bi_r);
    int res_i = in_l / in_r;
    string res_s = std::to_string(res_i);
    str.replace(div_l, div_r, res_s);
    }
}
```

The Edits Include:

1.Added checks for string::nops in line 20,22,28.

2.Changed length of string to replace with as div_l instead of  res_s.length() in line 40

Now,

taking an input =24/2/2

Output=6