# function string::substr shows Exception thrown at X. Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location X. during Debugging

Tags: c++, string, c++11, visual-c++, substring

Im making an equation solver which solves a mathematical equation when it gets any input.
The code  for division is:

```
void Calculation_div(string &str)
{
    std::size_t iter_a;
    std::size_t iter_r, iter_l;
    while(str.find('/') != string::npos) {
        iter_a = str.find('/');
        if (str.find('/', iter_a + 1) != string::npos || str.find('*',       iter_a + 1) != string::npos|| 
        str.find('-', iter_a + 1) != string::npos|| str.find('+', iter_a + 1) != string::npos) {
        iter_r = str.find('/', iter_a + 1);
        if (str.find('*', iter_a + 1) < iter_r) {
            iter_r = str.find('*', iter_a + 1);
        }
        if (str.find('-', iter_a + 1) < iter_r){
            iter_r = str.find('-', iter_a + 1);
        }
        if (str.find('+', iter_a + 1) < iter_r) {
            iter_r = str.find('+', iter_a + 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        iter_r = str.length();
    }
    if (str.rfind('/', iter_a - 1) != string::npos || str.rfind('*', iter_a - 1) != string::npos ||
        str.rfind('-', iter_a - 1) != string::npos || str.rfind('+', iter_a - 1) != string::npos) {
        iter_l = str.rfind('/', iter_a - 1);
        if (str.rfind('*', iter_a - 1) > iter_l && iter_l!=string::npos) {
            iter_l = str.rfind('*', iter_a - 1);
        }
        if (str.rfind('-', iter_a - 1) > iter_r && iter_l != string::npos) {
            iter_l = str.rfind('-', iter_a - 1);
        }
        if (str.rfind('+', iter_a - 1) > iter_r && iter_l!=string::npos) {
            iter_l = str.rfind('+', iter_a - 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        iter_l = 0;
    }
    string bi_l = str.substr(iter_l, (iter_a - iter_l+1));
    string bi_r = str.substr(iter_a+1, (iter_r - iter_a+1));
    float do_l = stod(bi_l);
    double do_r = stod(bi_r);
    double res_i = do_l / do_r;
        string res_s = std::to_string(res_i);
        str.replace(iter_l, iter_r - iter_l, res_s, 0, iter_r - iter_l -2);
        cout << str << "\n";
    }
}
```

the code for addition:

```
void Calculation_plus(string &str)
{
std::size_t iter_a;
std::size_t iter_r, iter_l;
while (str.find('+') != string::npos) {
    iter_a = str.find('+');
    if (str.find('+', iter_a + 1) != string::npos) {
        iter_r = str.find('+', iter_a + 1);
    }
    else {
        iter_r = str.length();
    }
    if (str.rfind('+', iter_a - 1) != string::npos) {
        iter_l = str.rfind('+', iter_a - 1);
    }
    else {
        iter_l = 0;
    }
    string bi_l = str.substr(iter_l, (iter_a - iter_l));
    string bi_r = str.substr(iter_a + 1, (iter_r - iter_a + 1));
    double do_l = stod(bi_l);
    double do_r = stod(bi_r);
    double res_i = do_l + do_r;
    string res_s = std::to_string(res_i);
    str.replace(iter_l, iter_r-iter_l,res_s,0, iter_r - iter_l-2);
    cout << str<<"\n";
    }
}
```

But when I put the value of str as 22+22/22 it returns the following error

> Exception thrown at 0x75F8DB18 in ConsoleApplication1.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::out_of_range at memory location 0x0133EF90.
>   It seems the problem lies in the line

```
string bi_l = str.substr(iter_l, (iter_a - iter_l+1));
```

of both calculation_div and calculation_plus.
But even then i cant find out the problem as everything seems correct to me.

Comment: If that line was correct, then you wouldn't get an exception. Just check all the values before the exception is thrown. And please don't call those variables `iter`; they are not of type `std::string::iterator`.

Comment: *I'm making an equation solver which solves a mathematical equation when it gets any input.* -- FYI, the way you're going about doing this isn't the way it should be done.  Lookup "production rules" and "recursive descent parser".  [Also, I see that all you did was to implement addition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42769104/unhandled-exception-at-in-consoleapplication1-exe-microsoft-c-exception-std), and your code ballooned into what you have now.  That's what happens when you don't write a formal parser for this -- code that becomes hard-to-maintain and use.

Comment: And in any event, your program probably gives the wrong answer even if you didn't get the exception.  The division is done first, as per the order of operations, not the addition.  How do you control that?

Comment: When you get the exception in Visual Studio, press `Ctrl+Alt+C` to open the callstack and examine the arguments for `string.substr()`. That should tell you which index variable is out of range.

Comment: Thnx. I really needed that tip.Im new to visual studio and programming in general. So this helps a lot